# Insert multiple records at once in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, batch-processing, bulkinsert

I've been researching a lot about how to insert multiple records in direct cassandra cqlsh console. I found something about batch, so I thought of using it with a loop (for, while) but it seems that Cassandra does not support batch.

How could insert multiple records in direct cassandra console? There is something like stored procedure in cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra does not (at this time) have stored procedures, but you should be able to accomplish this with a [batch statement](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html).  Essentially you should be able to encapsulate multiple `INSERT`s inside of `BEGIN BATCH` and `APPLY BATCH` statements.  This example is from the DataStax documentation on batch operations.

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, balance) VALUES ('user1', -8) USING TIMESTAMP 19998889022757000;
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, expense_id, amount, description, paid)
    VALUES ('user1', 1, 8, 'burrito', false);
APPLY BATCH;
```

Check the doc linked above for more information.

Edit:

If you are meaning to `INSERT` several million records at once, then you should consider other methods.  The cqlsh [COPY](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command is a viable alternative (for a few million records or less) or the [Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html) for 10 million or more.

Comment: I had given it a read, but in my case I want to insert 1, 10, 50 and 100 million records. It would be easier if I could use a "for" or "while".
Is there a way to insert many records using batch?

Comment: Batch has a serious drawback , it size is limited , you cannot add as many insert statements inside batch, will error out "Batch size too large"